# Show full comment form for logged user wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I made custom comment form with 2 extra fields.

Iv'e applied it for specific page, now I would like to show the full comment form (with the default & the extra fields) for logged user. By default wordpress only shows on the comment field (textarea).

This configuration must work only for a specific page.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: How are you calling the current comment form and the new one? You can use is_user_logged_in() for the condition.

Comment: Its copy of the default comment php file, have an idea how to call the full form by using the is_user_logged_in() ?

Comment: Use an if statement. if(is_user_logged_in()){ Display custom comment form }else{ Display default comment form } Can you paste the code of the custom comment form?